# 960 grid elements not displaying like I think they should

Tags: css, sass

I'm using the 960 grid system to layout a website. I'm having trouble getting the nivo-slider and an h1 tag to display side by side with a gutter in the middle. The two elements in question are both contained in one div, the slider has a class of

```
grid_7
```

and the h1 has a class of `grid_5`

These add up to 12 for the 12 column grid I'm using. I don't see why they are overlapping[image]

Here is my scss

```
@import "compass/reset";

body {
  background: url(../img/background.png);
}

#header {
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#navigation {
  clear: both;
  ul {
    li{
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
      margin: 2px;
      a {
       text-decoration: none;
     }
    }
  }
}

#content-wrapper {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without any html and the full css (you're including a file which might contain important classes), but it seems to me that if the h1 is #header then you need to give it float:left or display:inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem I was having.The two elements should not be in one containing div.

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped them both in container_12?

```
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_5"></div>
  <div class="grid_7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes they are wrapped in container_12